# Javascript: Using element height as pixel value to set properties of other elements

Tags: javascript, css, height, margins

I'm trying to set the height and margins of some elements based on the height of another, but it isn't working.

```
  function matchHeight(divName) {
    var Sheight = document.getElementById(divName).style.height;

    document.getElementById('bookmark').style.height = Sheight + '45px';
    document.getElementById('bookmarkend').style.marginTop = Sheight + '45px';
    document.getElementById('bookmarktagI').style.height = Sheight + '255px';
  }
```

What's wrong with my function?

I'd rather do it without jquery, if possible.

Comment: Well debugging step number one would be `console.log(Sheight)` - see if it is (a) the value you expect, and (b) something that it makes sense to concatenate `'45px'` onto...

Comment: `style.height` returns something like `100px`, then you add `45px`, and you get `100px45px` which is not a valid value ?

Comment: What exactly do you expect? And can you also add some html please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your styles are set inline, i.e. `<div style="height: 100px;"></div>`, then most probably your problem is in parsing `height` style value. In this case `Sheight` will be `"100px"`, which will simply concatenate with other values forming something like `100px45px`, which isn't really good.

To solve the problem parse the value to integer with `parseInt` and use correct addition:

```
var Sheight = parseInt(document.getElementById(divName).style.height, 10);
document.getElementById('bookmark').style.height = (Sheight + 45) + 'px';
```

Comment: Works great! You're brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function matchHeight(divName) {
  var Sheight = parseInt(document.getElementById(divName).style.height);

  document.getElementById('bookmark').style.height = Sheight + 45 + 'px';
  document.getElementById('bookmarkend').style.marginTop = Sheight + 45 + 'px';
  document.getElementById('bookmarktagI').style.height = Sheight + 255 + 'px';
}
```

Your + will be treated as string concatenation otherwise which will give you wrong values.

Comment: Doesn't its need to be like `height = Sheight + 45 + 'px'; ` ?

Comment: You actually do need the px, and in javascript styles are strings, as in the returned value is '100px' etc.